# More than one DbContext in the same project

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a WebAPI project and in this project I have to use more than one DbContext but I do not know how to do that.
There are 3 or 4 databases and with code first I will create a new table in each of them and give relation to the table that is found in each database

How can I do this in a generic way?

Comment: you mean the data fragmented across multiple databases? example the name is in one database 1 and the address is in the other

Comment: A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work containing entities meant to handle specific scenarios, not a database connection or model. You can have as many as you want in a project, targeting the same or different databases and even the same tables but mapping to different entities

Comment: `This is a project I have to do urgently would you mind please help me how can I do this in a generic way ?` in that case post enough information so people can help. Right now there's no real question except `can I have many DbContexts ?` Yes, just add them. `I will create a new table in each of them and give relation to the table that is found in each database` what does that mean? What entities are involved? PostgreSQL doesn't allow cross-database queries so you can't have relations between tables in different databases

Comment: could you add more information or give an example

Comment: The question is unclear. Perhaps you're asking how to connect to multiple databases using the same DbContext type (pass a different connection string in the constructor), perhaps you're asking how to create multiple DbContext-derived classes (just create them), or you're asking how to include tables from different databases in the same DbContext - PostgreSQL doesn't allow a query to refer to multiple databases, and EF Core only connects to one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

to have multiple databases. they should be added to the services.
example :

```
var connectionString1 = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db1Connection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbfirstDbContext>(options =>
     options. UseSqlServer(connectionString));

var connectionString2 = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db2Connection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbtwoDbContext>(options =>
     options. UseSqlServer(connectionString2));
```